# SQLDataReader. ExecuteReader times out

Tags: c#, sql, .net

MS sql 2014 backend (on same machine) - `Executereader times out (native error code: 258) @ second executereader()` in same connection. Why is this so?
(No big data amount involved, cmd strings involved are correct)

Note: it doesn't matter if all SELECT goes into separate connection the second always times out. It also doesn't matter if I'd use DataAdapter to catch data.... times out... see below, thanks for the ideas:

```
using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection(cString))
{
    c.Open();
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(querystringPO, c))
    {

        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramRecipe", productionOrderNo);
        using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            dtRecipe = new DataTable();
            dtRecipe.Load(rd);
            rd.Close();
        }
    }
    if (dtRecipe.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
        string querystringOpDefs = "SELECT * FROM ReferencedFieldsView_OperationDefinition WHERE RecipeID=@paramOpDef";
        using (SqlCommand cmd1 = new SqlCommand(querystringOpDefs, c))
        {

            cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramOpDef", dtRecipe.Rows[0].Field<int>("ID"));
            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd1.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dtOpDefs = new DataTable();
                dtOpDefs.Load(rd);
                rd.Close();
            }


        }
        string querystringBOMItems = "SELECT * FROM ReferencedFieldsView_BomItem WHERE RecipeID=@paramBOMItem";

        using (SqlCommand cmd2 = new SqlCommand(querystringBOMItems, c))
        {

            cmd2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@paramBOMItem", dtRecipe.Rows[0].Field<int>("ID"));
            using (SqlDataReader rd = cmd2.ExecuteReader())
            {
                dtBOMItems = new DataTable();
                dtBOMItems.Load(rd);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Ex below:

> > Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: Server operation encountered an exception ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding. ---> System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: The wait operation timed out
> >        --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString, Boolean isInternal, Boolean forDescribeParameterEncryption, Boolean shouldCacheForAlwaysEncrypted)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry, SqlDataReader ds, Boolean describeParameterEncryptionRequest)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean& usedCache, Boolean asyncWrite, Boolean inRetry)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> >        at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()

Comment: Post the full exception, including the call stack and any inner exceptions. You can get that very easily with `Exception.ToString()`. You didn't even post the message which could explain what kind of timeout it was. Don't just post the message though, post the *full* exception

Comment: As for why timeouts occur, if it's command timeouts, it's typically because of bad queries and missing indexes. The way to fix them is to fix the queries and add proper indexes. If there are a lot of data and no optimization is possible, the timeout should be increased

Comment: The names of the views suggest you're running a BOM query. Those are similar to hierarchical queries and can be very slow unless special care is taken. The typical way to implement them is to use recursion, which is slow. Or, you can replace the `Parent/ChildID` relation with a `hierarchyid` field and get *very* fast queries

Comment: Use SQL Server Management Studio and run you query on SSMS.  The error messages in SSMS are 1000 times better than c# for debugging these type issues.

Comment: Edited description, no big amount of data involved (only for testing 1-2 records to get back) and cmd strings are OK. Tested in SSMS

Comment: `SELECT * FROM ReferencedFieldsView_BomItem WHERE RecipeID=@paramBOMItem` takes more than 30 seconds to get going and cough up data. This is either because the query is expensive to execute (for whatever reason, and note that things can be [different](http://www.sommarskog.se/query-plan-mysteries.html) between SMSS and the application) or because locks are being held that don't allow the query to proceed, or because there's a network problem that somehow eats the response from SQL Server to the application (roughly in decreasing order of probability).

Comment: sql server is on the same machine along with the dev.env. I don't know why the lock occurs after the 1st query, nothing expensive in those :(

Comment: So you've established there's a lock then, or is that speculating? You can use `sys.dm_os_waiting_tasks` to see if the query is actually blocked, and why. Having a local server only establishes that the problem is not the network; it can still be the execution plan.

Answer (score 0):

Fact of the matter is that using SQL 2K12 the above snippet all worked (same database same etc)

However as sb suggested instead of selecting all fields (*), when explicitly added the req'd fields it started to work.